# Tensorflow2 Warning: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder ..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I get the following warning when running the following minimal code (that will train a very simple tensorflow 2 model). Actually it is telling me that I can ignore this message, but I still got the feeling that something might be wrong and I don't like ignoring messages like this. The message still persists even if I set verbose=0.

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_1' with dtype double and shape [5000,25,1]
[[{{node Placeholder/_1}}]]

I am using tensorflow 2.12.0.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Reshape
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.rand(5000, 10, 7)
y = np.random.rand(5000, 25, 1)

#############################################################
# create the dataset
#############################################################
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
ds = ds.batch(32, drop_remainder=True)

#############################################################
# construct the model
#############################################################
inputs = []

x = Input(shape=(10, 7))
inputs.append(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(25)(x)
x = Reshape((25, 1))(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

model.compile(loss="mse")
model.summary()

#############################################################
# fit the model
#############################################################
model.fit(ds, batch_size=10, verbose=1, epochs=10)
```

**Output**

```
2023-04-10 17:32:46.805357: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-10 17:32:47.312460: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-04-10 17:32:50.162190: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2578 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Quadro T1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 10, 7)]           0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 70)                0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 25)                1775      
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 25, 1)             0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,775
Trainable params: 1,775
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
2023-04-10 17:32:50.244149: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_1' with dtype double and shape [5000,25,1]
     [[{{node Placeholder/_1}}]]
2023-04-10 17:32:50.804972: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169] XLA service 0x7f6e808f79c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2023-04-10 17:32:50.804996: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:177]   StreamExecutor device (0): Quadro T1000, Compute Capability 7.5
2023-04-10 17:32:50.807856: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:269] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
2023-04-10 17:32:50.909253: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:424] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
2023-04-10 17:32:50.946872: I tensorflow/tsl/platform/default/subprocess.cc:304] Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory
2023-04-10 17:32:50.981030: I ./tensorflow/compiler/jit/device_compiler.h:180] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
156/156 [==============================] - 1s 986us/step - loss: 0.2249
Epoch 2/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 958us/step - loss: 0.1457
Epoch 3/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 981us/step - loss: 0.1185
Epoch 4/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 929us/step - loss: 0.1026
Epoch 5/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0940
Epoch 6/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 929us/step - loss: 0.0895
Epoch 7/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 960us/step - loss: 0.0872
Epoch 8/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 958us/step - loss: 0.0860
Epoch 9/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 969us/step - loss: 0.0854
Epoch 10/10
156/156 [==============================] - 0s 998us/step - loss: 0.0851

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what's even more strange is that if I am adding the line:
ds = ds.shuffle(5000)
before ds.batch(...) then I am getting the same Warning twice.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not an error. It is just a "debug info", which is very misleading. There is an open issue in the tensorflow repo if you want to read more: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59779

You can disable the output spam with the following code. However, you might loose out on actually important information when setting the log level to 2:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

or in the shell:

```
export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using tensorflow 2.12.0 as well, however downgrading to 2.10* helped me fix that error.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow==2.10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).